# Android NullPointer Exception AsyncTask

Tags: android, file-upload, android-asynctask

i want to send messages with attached files using asyncTask,
my php code is ok .. becausewhen uploading small size files everyting will be ok and when i send messages wihtout attachement everything will be as i want .. but when uploading file with big size (like apk files that are > 6 Mb) i got null pointer exception in this line : (look in onPostExecute)

```
                success2 = json2.getInt("success");
```

here is the asyncTasck

```
  public class PostDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                try {
       uploadFile(fichier);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
        int  success2= 0;
        try {
            success2 = json2.getInt("success");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(success2==1) {
            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMsg)).setText("");
            if (attach) {
                changerAttach();
                }     }
     } }
```

and here is the upload functopn:

```
  private void uploadFile(String filePath) {
    try {
        try {

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url_upload);
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            entity.addPart("Mdp", new StringBody(mdp));
            entity.addPart("Msg", new StringBody(URLEncoder.encode(msg)));
            entity.addPart("type", new StringBody(type));
            if(type.equals("1")) {
                entity.addPart("Emailm", new StringBody(email));
                entity.addPart("Emailp", new StringBody(emaildest));
            }else {
                entity.addPart("Emailp", new StringBody(email));
                entity.addPart("Emailm", new StringBody(emaildest));
            }
            if (attach){
                entity.addPart("attachement", new FileBody(new File(filePath)));
                entity.addPart("attacher", new StringBody("oui"));
            }else{
                entity.addPart("attacher", new StringBody("non"));
            }

            httpost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response;
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);

            if (response != null) {
                HttpEntity entity2 = response.getEntity();
                String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity2, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(responseString);
                json2=new JSONObject(responseString);

            } else { //erreur
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Note the String "**fichier**" the path of the file that i want to apload.

**attach** is boolean variable that means that i have choosen file to upload or not.

**json2** is a global variable (JSONObject) that will be initialed in the upload function

i think this is what you need (the php code is ok)

Note: i think that the concurence is what cause my problem so is this true ?
thanks a lot

**EDIT**
the upload.php

```
    <?php  
date_default_timezone_set ("Africa/Algiers");
include('connect.php');
$response = array();

if (isset($_REQUEST['Emailm'])&& isset($_REQUEST['Mdp'])&&isset($_REQUEST['type']) && isset($_REQUEST['Emailp'])&&isset($_REQUEST['Msg'])  ) {


    $Emailm = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Emailm']);  
    $Emailp = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Emailp']); 
    $Mdp = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Mdp']);  
    $Msg = $_REQUEST['Msg'];  
    $Mdp = $_REQUEST['Mdp'];  
    $Msg= $db->real_escape_string(htmlentities(urldecode($Msg)));    
    $type= $_REQUEST['type'];
    $target_path1 = "attachement/";   
    if($type=="0"){  //compte patient
    if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE `Email_p`='$Emailp' AND `Mdp`='$Mdp'")) {
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows; }
     }else {  //compte médecin
    if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `med` WHERE `Email`='$Emailm' AND `Mdp`='$Mdp'")) {
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows; } 
    }


    $b=false;
    $a=false;

    if ($row_cnt>0) {  
                if($_REQUEST['attacher']=="oui"){   
                $filecount = 0;
                $files = glob($target_path1 . "*");
                if ($files){
                $filecount = count($files);
                }
                $nomFichier=$filecount.basename( $_FILES['attachement']['name'])  ; 
                $target_path1 = $target_path1 . $nomFichier;
                $nomFichierOrigin=basename( $_FILES['attachement']['name']);
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachement']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
                $b=true;} 
                }
                else{
                $nomFichier="";
                $nomFichierOrigin="";
                };

                       $h=new DateTime("now") ;
                       $s=$h->format('G:i:s');
                       $s2=$h->format('Y-m-d');
                    if($result = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO `msg`(`cle`, `email_m`, `email_p`, `message`, `attachement`, `type`, `attachementNomOrigin`, `heure`, `date`,`vu`) 
                    VALUES ('','$Emailm','$Emailp','$Msg','$nomFichier','$type','$nomFichierOrigin','$s','$s2','non')"))
                    {$a=true;}

                    if($a==true && $b==true && $_REQUEST['attacher']=="oui"){
                     $dernierId = $db->insert_id;   
                     if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `med` WHERE `Email`='$Emailm' AND `Mdp`='$Mdp'")) {
                     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
                      $response["Msg"] = array();
                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $Msg = array();
                    $Msg["cle"] = intval($row["cle"]);
                    $Msg["heure"] = $row["heure"];
                    $Msg["date"] = $row["date"];
                    $Msg["email_m"] = $row["email_m"]; 
                    $Msg["email_p"] = $row["email_p"]; 
                    $Msg["message"] = $row["message"]; 
                    $Msg["type"] = $row["type"];  
                    $Msg["attachement"] = $row["attachement"]; 
                    $Msg["attachementNomOrigin"] = $row["attachementNomOrigin"]; 
                    array_push($response["Msg"], $Msg);
                     }

                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    $response["message"] = "Succès";
                    }}} else 

                    if($a==true && $_REQUEST['attacher']=="non"){
                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    $response["message"] = "Succès"; 
                    }else{

                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Erreur lors de l'envoi";
                    }

                    echo json_encode($response);
    } else { 
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Email ou Mot de passe incorrect";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}else { 
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Champs manqués";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

the logCat :

```
04-20 18:05:00.149    4509-4509/eddine.charef.mechalikh.swipedemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at eddine.charef.mechalikh.swipedemo.message$PostDataAsyncTask.onPostExecute(message.java:231)
            at eddine.charef.mechalikh.swipedemo.message$PostDataAsyncTask.onPostExecute(message.java:207)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4813)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 18:05:00.219    4509-6923/eddine.charef.mechalikh.swipedemo I/System.out﹕ {"Msg":[{"cle":271,"heure":"18:01:18","date":"2015-04-20","email_m":"mecha","email_p":"a","message":"hhhh","type":"0","attachement":"12Maps.apk","attachementNomOrigin":"Maps.apk"}],"success":1,"message":"Msg telecharg\u00e9s"}
```

In the jsonParser i've odd this

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(json);
```

and you can see the json object in the logcat even when exception rised ...so it is a timing problem .. what do you think ?

**Edit2** 
the JsonParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){};

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(json);
        //HERE IS THE SYSTEM.OUT.PRINT THAT I TALK ABOUT
        //YOU CAN SEE THE RESULT IN THE LOGCAT
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

to give you an idea about what am facing :
i want to clear tha EdittextHere :[image: screenshot]
after sending the message that's why i check the success tag in the postExecute ..if you have other ways i will apreciate that .. note that this is my first app, so i didn't know other ways to do this

Comment: what is `json2` in `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: Was the file successfully uploaded in the case when you get this error?  It looks to me like `response` is `null`, so `json2` will be null as well.  This call is probably returning `null` in this case: `response = httpclient.execute(httpost);`

Comment: when i brouse the attachement folder i can open or read that file .. which means that it was successfully uploaded even if tha application stopped, you're right i had to mention this

Comment: why in case of small file like (200 Kb size)..why in this case the there is no exception ?

Comment: BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response .getEntity().getContent())); String msg=""; String line = ""; while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) { msg += line; } Log.i("msg=",""+msg);

Comment: Add the above code after response = httpclient.execute(httpost); and check your msg.

Comment: look at my edit ... i found something that will help a lot

Comment: in the System.out.print ... in the logcat you can see"Maps.apk .. it is google maps app ..its size is about 10 Mb and wes uploaded successfully ... i downloaded it with my appand installed it ..

Comment: i added that .. i will test it and report

Comment: Instead of System.out, Log.i also works fine and shows a similar response.

Comment: i added the jsonparser.java

Comment: when added yout lines here is what i got : 04-20 18:18:59.869  20206-21260/eddine.charef.mechalikh.swipedemo I/msg=﹕ []

Comment: no just one file per message

Comment: Wait a second.... where do you call `makeHttpRequest()`?

Comment: i don't use the makehttpRequest here.. i use : response = httpclient.execute(httpost);  to send multipartEntity which contains texts and file

Comment: But it looks like the `System.out` call with valid JSON results is coming from `makeHttpRequest()`, right?

Comment: aaaa yes i forget .. your right ... after sending the message i have a timer that upfate the message list ...i use for that the "makehttprequest" sorry about that ..your right ...

Comment: here is how i did it .. i send the message ... if the message wes sucessfully sent .. i clear the textEdit...and the attached file .. and set attach to "false" ...that's why i use the success tag in the json object ..(i think that i understand now where is the problem) ..so after uploading and clearing those things .. a timer will update the message list

Comment: now i know where is the problem ..i have to add this Log.i("json=",""+String.valueOf(json)); after this : json2=new JSONObject(responseString);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75745/discussion-between-daniel-nugent-and-charef-eddine-mechalikh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the php code .. here is the correct one

```
    <?php  
date_default_timezone_set ("Africa/Algiers");
include('connect.php');
$response = array();

if (isset($_REQUEST['Emailm'])&& isset($_REQUEST['Mdp'])&&isset($_REQUEST['type']) && isset($_REQUEST['Emailp'])&&isset($_REQUEST['Msg'])  ) {

    $Emailm = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Emailm']);  
    $Emailp = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Emailp']); 
    $Mdp = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Mdp']);  
    $Msg = $_REQUEST['Msg'];  
    $Mdp = $_REQUEST['Mdp'];  
    $Msg= $db->real_escape_string(htmlentities(urldecode($Msg)));    
    $type= $_REQUEST['type'];
    $target_path1 = "attachement/";   
    if($type=="0"){  //compte patient
    if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE `Email_p`='$Emailp' AND `Mdp`='$Mdp'")) {
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows; 
 }
     }else {  //compte médecin
    if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `med` WHERE `Email`='$Emailm' AND `Mdp`='$Mdp'")) {
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows; 
 } 
    }


    $b=false;
    $a=false;

    if ($row_cnt>0) {  
                if($_REQUEST['attacher']=="oui"){       
                $filecount = 0;
                $files = glob($target_path1 . "*");
                if ($files){
                $filecount = count($files); 
                }
                $nomFichier=$filecount.basename( $_FILES['attachement']['name']) . ".a"; 
                $target_path1 = $target_path1 . $nomFichier;
                $nomFichierOrigin=basename( $_FILES['attachement']['name']);
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachement']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) {
                $b=true; } 
                }
                else{
                $nomFichier="";
                $nomFichierOrigin=""; 
                };

                       $h=new DateTime("now") ;
                       $s=$h->format('G:i:s');
                       $s2=$h->format('Y-m-d');
                    if($result = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO `msg`(`cle`, `email_m`, `email_p`, `message`, `attachement`, `type`, `attachementNomOrigin`, `heure`, `date`,`vu`) 
                    VALUES ('','$Emailm','$Emailp','$Msg','$nomFichier','$type','$nomFichierOrigin','$s','$s2','non')"))
                    {$a=true;$dernierId = $db->insert_id;
                     }

                    if($a==true && $b==true && $_REQUEST['attacher']=="oui"){


                     if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM msg WHERE cle='$dernierId'")) {
                     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
                      $response["Msg"] = array();
                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $Msg = array();
                    $Msg["cle"] = intval($row["cle"]);
                    $Msg["heure"] = $row["heure"];
                    $Msg["date"] = $row["date"];
                    $Msg["email_m"] = $row["email_m"]; 
                    $Msg["email_p"] = $row["email_p"]; 
                    $Msg["message"] = $row["message"]; 
                    $Msg["type"] = $row["type"];  
                    $Msg["attachement"] = $row["attachement"]; 
                    $Msg["attachementNomOrigin"] = $row["attachementNomOrigin"]; 
                    array_push($response["Msg"], $Msg);
                     }

                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    $response["message"] = "Succès"; 
                    }}} else 

                    if($a==true && $_REQUEST['attacher']=="non"){ 
                    $response["success"] = 1;
                    $response["message"] = "Succès"; 
                    }else{ 
                    $response["success"] = 0;
                    $response["message"] = "Erreur lors de l'envoi";
                    }


    } else {  
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Email ou Mot de passe incorrect";


    }
}else { 

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Champs manqués";


} echo json_encode($response);
?>
```